# A good strategy/solution for concurrency with hibernate's optimistic/pessimistic locking

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, concurrency, locking

Let's presume that we have an application "mail client" and a front-end for it.

If a user is typing a message or editing the subject or whatever, a rest call is made to update whatever the user was changing (e.g. the receivers) to keep the message in DRAFT. So a lot PUT's are happening to save the message. When closing the window, an update of every editable field happens at the same time. Hibernate can't handle this concurrency: Each of those calls retrieve the message, edit their own fields and try to save the message again, while the other call already changed it.

I know I can add a rest call to save all fields at the same time, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner solution, or a decent strategy to handle such cases (like for example only updating one field or some merge strategy if the object has already changed)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=hibernate+update+single+column&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=hibernate+update+single+field

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solutions here would be to tweak the UI to either

- Submit a single rest call during email submission that does all the tasks necessary.
- Serialize the rest calls so they're chained rather than firing concurrently.

The concern I have here is that this will snowball at some point and become a bigger concurrency problem as more users are interacting with the application.  Consider for the moment the potential number of concurrent rest calls your web infrastructure will have to support alone when you're faced with a 100, 500, 1000, or even 10000 or more concurrent users.

Does it really make sense to beef up the volume of servers to handle that load when the load itself is a product of a design flaw in the first place?

Hibernate is designed to handle locking through two mechanisms, optimistic and pessimistic.

*Optimistic Way*

1. Read the entity from the data store.
2. Cache a copy of the fields you're going to modify in temporary variables.
3. Modify the field or fields based on your `PUT` operation.
4. Attempt to merge the changes.
5. If save succeeds, you're done.
6. Should an `OptimisticLockException` occur, refresh the entity state from data store.
7. Compare cached values to the fields you must change.
8. If values differ, you can assert or throw an exception
9. If they don't differ, go back to 4.

The beautiful part of the *optimistic* approach is you avoid any form of deadlock happening, particularly if you're allowing multiple tables to be read and locked separately.

While you can use pessimistic lock options, optimistic locking is generally the best accepted way to handle concurrent operations as it has the least concurrency contention and performance impact.

Comment: Right now, I've chained the calls (quick fix). But as you pointed out, this is very problematic once the application scales up. I would prefer not to do a single call with all fields each time a field changes. I was thinking of using single update statements with hibernate... This way, the object doesn't need to be retrieved -> concurrency solved for those calls... Though I'm wondering what the impact will be for the full application, since it's not just a simple mail client, but a full blown business solution for encrypted messaging which does a lot of scheduled postprocessing with the obj's

Comment: I updated my answer to include an idea using optimistic locking.  You certainly can fire pure `UPDATE` statements but that doesn't solve the concern of what happens should some other process modify a field that the user is trying to modify.  Your pure `UPDATE` approach accepts the notion that the last one wins rather than forcing the non-first to review their changes should conflicts have occurred.